# Plotting all columns in a dataframe to a single graph Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that has x-many columns (x varies by the input of the user). I want to be able to plot all of the columns in each dataframe to a single histogram.

Some of the code for this loop looks like this so far:

```
for var_name in variables:

    df_var = (rand_sample.filter(like=str(var_name))) # filter on each variable for comparison
    print(df_var)

    # Plot Frequency
    fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
    plt.hist([df_var], alpha=0.35, bins=bin_size)
    plt.title(str(j), fontsize=18)
    plt.xlabel('Porosity Density', fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=15)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Where `variables` is a list previously made with wanted strings that I'm filtering to group together in `df_var`.

I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 107574 to array axis with dimension 2
```

Which means there are `2 columns` trying to be plotted as `1 column` here - I understand this; I just don't know how to write the code to make `plt.hist([df_var]...)` work for any number of columns.

Comment: Maybe try `plt.hist(df_var.values.flatten(), alpha=0.35, bins=bin_size)`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Not sure if it's an infinite loop or a memory issue but after 10 mins of running I get nothing.

Comment: You would benefit from providing a [mcve]. Also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)